# Check if TcpListener is available to accept connection from client without connecting immediately

Tags: c#

I'm writing a c# application and I have some forms in which users can insert Ip address and port of TCP Listeners that are in other hosts.
So I would check if there is a tcp listener before to continue with the programm.
I don't want to use connect because I don't want to connect to these servers in the same time in witch I perform the control.

So for example
There is a listener

```
TcpListener server=new  TcpListener(IP,Port);
             server.start();
```

In the client application user insert Ip and port of many listeners that I will put in a list so:

```
//User insert ip and port
// PERFORM check: is there a listener at this ip and port?
```

than put in a list of available servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this in a general way. It is not possible to determine whether there is a server socket listening at the remote endpoint, not on your local machine, without actually trying to connect.

Note that this is a variation on the "file exists?" problem, and has the same general answer: don't do that.

Even if you could confirm the presence of a remote server prior to a connection attempt, it doesn't matter because the server could stop working between the time you check for it, and the time you actually try to connect.

So you have to handle the scenario where you attempt to connect to a server and fail anyway. Finding out in advance doesn't make things easier on you, and it doesn't really help the user very much either.

If you *really* want to validate the user's input, you can in fact go ahead and connect to the server, and then immediately disconnect (with graceful closure...i.e. call `Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send)` and wait for a 0-byte receive to complete before you actually close/dispose the `Socket` instance).

But personally, I'd just accept the user's input and then if later it turns out to be invalid, let them know when you actually find out that it is.